# how to assign an id number to a To Do task?

Tags: java

I have one class which will be used to create to do lists. This is the result of the test:

```
-----------------------------------------
TESTS - CONSTRUCTOR 1
-----------------------------------------
Construction todo ("description 1")... ➤            [⍡] - 1) description 1 () **(expected result in the test)**
id: 1 (System.out.println of the id in the test class)
➤            [⍡] - 1) description 1 **(result)**
OK **(the test is ok)**
Construction todo ("")... OK
Construction todo (null)... OK

------------------------------------------
TESTS - CONSTRUCTOR 2 
------------------------------------------
Construction todo (23/08/2016, "description 2")... id : 2 **(here id is 2)**
➤ 23/08/2016 [⍡] - 2) description 2
OK
Construction todo (null, "description 3")... id : 3 **(here id is 3)**
OK
Construction todo (01/01/2016, "xxx")... OK
Construction todo (10/09/2016, "")... OK
Construction todo (10/09/2016, null)... OK

------------------------------------------
TESTS - CONSTRUCTOR 3 
------------------------------------------
Construction todo (15/07/2016, "description 4", Todo.HIGH_IMPORTANCE)... **expected** : ➤ 15/07/2016 [⍥] - 4) description 4
**but i got** : ➤ 15/07/2016 [⍥] - 5) description 4 **(on this line the id is 5 instead of 4)**
id: 5 **(System.out.println of the id in test class)**
ERROR **(thats why i have here error)**
Construction todo (null, "description 5", Todo.MEDIUM_IMPORTANCE... id : 6 **(System.out.println in the test class)**
ERROR
Construction todo (01/01/2016, "xxx", Todo.HIGH_IMPORTANCE)... OK
Construction todo (10/09/2016, "", Todo.HIGH_IMPORTANCE)... OK
Construction todo (10/09/2016, null, Todo.HIGH_IMPORTANCE)... OK

------------------------
TESTS - GETTERS
------------------------
GET ID... OK
GET Date creation... OK
GET Dead line... OK
GET Description... OK
GET Description... OK
IS COMPLETED... OK

------------------------
TESTS - SETTERS
------------------------
SET Dead line... OK
SET Completed... OK
SET Level importance... OK
SET Level importance invalid... OK

Checking if the level of importance has not changed... **we expect** : ➤            [⍨] - 5) description 5
**printed result**: ➤            [⍨] - 6) description 5 **(here id is not good, need to be 5)**
ERROR
SET Description... OK
SET Description empty... OK
Checking that the description has not been changed... **we expect** : ➤ 15/07/2016 [⍥] - 4) description 4
**printed result**: ➤ 15/07/2016 [⍥] - 5) description 4
ERROR **(THAT'S WHY ERROR)**
SET Description null... OK
Checking that the description has not been changed... **we expect** : ➤ 15/07/2016 [⍥] - 4) description 4
**printed result**: ➤ 15/07/2016 [⍥] - 5) description 4
ERROR

----------------------------------------------------
TESTS - METHOD OBTENIR GETING LAST ID ASSUMED
----------------------------------------------------
Last id assumed = 5...  **id printed is 7**... ERROR

---------------------------------------
TESTS - METHOD HAS PRIORITY OVER
---------------------------------------
Test 1... OK
Test 2... OK
Test 3... OK
Test 4... OK
Test 5... OK
Test 6... OK
Test 7... OK
Test 8... OK
Test 9... OK
Test 10... OK
```

And this is my class:

```
public class Todo {


public static final int HIGH_IMPORTANCE = 1;
public static final int MEDIUM_IMPORTANCE = 2;
public static final int LOW_IMPORTANCE = 3;


private static int lastIdAssumed = 0;


private Date dateCreation;
private Date deadline;
private String description;
private int levelImportance;
private boolean completed;
private int id;


public Todo(String description) throws TodoInvalideException{
    if (description != null && description.length() != 0) {
        this.description = description;
    } else {
        throw new TodoInvalideException();
    }

    this.dateCreation = Date.todayDate ();
    this.deadline = null;
    this.levelImportance = LOW_IMPORTANCE;
    this.completed = false;
    lastIdAssumed = lastIdAssumed + 1;
    this.id = lastIdAssumed;

}

public Todo(Date deadline, String description)throws TodoInvalideException, DateInvalideException {
    this(description);
    if (deadline != null && dateCreation.estPlusRecente(deadline)){
        throw new TodoInvalideException ();
    }

    this.deadline = deadline;

}

public Todo(Date deadline, String description, int levelImportance)throws TodoInvalideException, DateInvalideException{
    this(deadline, description);


    if (levelImportance == HIGH_IMPORTANCE || levelImportance == MEDIUM_IMPORTANCE 
    || levelImportance == LOW_IMPORTANCE) { 
        this.levelImportance = levelImportance;
    } else {
        throw new TodoInvalideException();
    }

}


//GETTERS (6)
public Date getDateCreation(){
    return dateCreation;
}

public Date getDeadline(){
    return deadline;
}

public String getDescription(){
    return description;
}

public boolean isCompleted(){
    return completed;
}

public int getLevelImportance(){
    return levelImportance;
}

public int getId(){
    return id;
}

//SETTERS (4)

public void setDeadline(Date deadline){
    this.deadline = deadline;
}

public void setDescription(String description) throws TodoInvalideException {

    if (description != null && description.length() != 0) {
        this.description = description;
    } else {
        throw new TodoInvalideException();
    }

}

public void setCompleted(boolean completed){
    this.completed = completed;
}

public void setLevelImportance(int levelImportance) throws TodoInvalideException {

    if (levelImportance == HIGH_IMPORTANCE || levelImportance == MEDIUM_IMPORTANCE 
    || levelImportance == LOW_IMPORTANCE) { 
        this.levelImportance = levelImportance;
    } else {
        throw new TodoInvalideException();
    }

}


public boolean hasPriorityOver (Todo anotherTodo) throws TodoInvalideException, DateInvalideException {
    boolean priorityTodo = false;

    if (this.deadline == null && anotherTodo.deadline == null) {
        if (this.levelImportance < anotherTodo.levelImportance) {
            priorityTodo = true;
        }

    } else if (this.deadline == null && anotherTodo.deadline != null) {
        priorityTodo = false;

    } else if (this.deadline != null && anotherTodo.deadline == null) {
        priorityTodo = true;
    } 

    if(this.deadline != null && anotherTodo.deadline != null) {

        if (anotherTodo.deadline.isMoreRecent(this.deadline)) { 
            priorityTodo = true;

        }else{
            priorityTodo = false;
        }

        if (this.deadline.isEquals(anotherTodo.deadline)) { 
            if (this.levelImportance < anotherTodo.levelImportance) { 
                priorityTodo = true;
            }else{
                priorityTodo = false;
            }

        }
    }

    return priorityTodo; 
}


public String toString () {
    String [] tab = {"", "[\u2365]", "[\u2368]", "[\u2361]"};
    String s = "";

    if (completed) {
        s = s + "\u2714";
    } else {
        s = s + "\u27A4";
    }
    if (deadline == null) {
        s = s + "           ";
    } else {
        s = s + " " + deadline;
    }

    s = s + " " + tab[levelImportance];
    s = s + " - " + id + ") " + description;

    return s;
}


public static int getingLastIdAssumed () {


    return lastIdAssumed; 
}

}
```

The methods isMoreRecent(), isEquals() and Date.todayDate () are in the other class named Date.
Thank you very much!

Comment: where is the question?

Comment: in my test i'm getting wrong id

Comment: More than likely, there is an unexpected ToDo class created somewhere, perhaps in the test driver. The fact that `id` is assigned from the `lastIdAssumed` (which is incremented), is suggestive. I am assuming the problem is what is shown in the output, but as @RamanShrivastava suggested, it would be easier if the question were more directly stated.

Answer (score 1):

See my explanation after the arrows

```
Construction todo (01/01/2016, "xxx")... OK   ---> invokes  Todo(String description), your static variable increased to 4
```

"xxx" is not null and length is bigger than 0, therefore it is okay to invoke Todo(String description). Unfortunately, the following 2 instantiations are failed due to description are either empty string or null value, static variable **lastIdAssumed** didn't change its value.

```
Construction todo (10/09/2016, "")... OK  ---> throws TodoInvalideException, static variable didn't increase
Construction todo (10/09/2016, null)... OK ---> throws TodoInvalideException, static variable didn't increase
```

Therefore, when you invoke below constructor, your static variable is 5.

```
Construction todo (15/07/2016, "description 4", Todo.HIGH_IMPORTANCE)
```

Comment: and how to fix that?

Comment: it is supposed to be 5. You can switch your test cases orders

Comment: sorry but still I don't quite understand what needs to change. :(

Comment: either 1) change "description 4" to "description 5"  2) move and invoke `Construction todo (15/07/2016, "description 4", Todo.HIGH_IMPORTANCE)` ahead of `
down vote
See my explanation after the arrows

Construction todo (01/01/2016, "xxx")`

Comment: I can't change the test file. I need to fix it in the code.